# What is the use of Log4j API?

Tags: log4j

I am going to use Log4j in my web application and I am new to that. What is the uses of Log4j and how I use it in my application. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the [Log4J home page](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html) offers the best overview and rationale behind its use.

> With log4j it is possible to enable
>   logging at runtime without modifying
>   the application binary. The log4j
>   package is designed so that these
>   statements can remain in shipped code
>   without incurring a heavy performance
>   cost. Logging behavior can be
>   controlled by editing a configuration
>   file, without touching the application
>   binary.
>
> Logging equips the developer with
>   detailed context for application
>   failures. On the other hand, testing
>   provides quality assurance and
>   confidence in the application. Logging
>   and testing should not be confused.
>   They are complementary. When logging
>   is wisely used, it can prove to be an
>   essential tool.

To add to this, with Log4J you can dynamically switch logging on/off. You can change the format dynamically (do you want timestamps ? datestamps ?) and you can change where the logging goes (to the console ? to a file ? to a database ?), all without changing your code.

Comment: You can also log to multiple sources at once. In an application I'm working on now, when I'm testing the application, I log to both the console (so I can see debug information as well as any errors that pop up) along with the standard log file that's always logged to. Quite handy.

Answer (score 2):

At its most basic level, you can think of it as a replacement for System.out.println's in your code. Why is it better than System.out.println's? The reasons are numerous.

To begin with, System.out.println outputs to standard output, which typically is a console window. The output from Log4j can go to the console, but it can also go to an email server, a databaseW table, a log file, or various other destinations.

Another great benefit of Log4j is that different levels of logging can be set. The levels are hierarchical and are as follows: TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, and FATAL. If you set a particular log level, messages will get logged for that level and all levels above it, and not for any log levels below that. As an example, if your log level is set to ERROR, you will log messages that are errors and fatals. If your log level is set to INFO, you will log messages that are infos, warns, errors, and fatals. Typically, when you develop on your local machine, it's good to set the log level to DEBUG, and when you deploy a web application, you should set the log level to INFO or higher so that you don't fill up your error logs with debug messages.

Log4j can do other great things. For instance, you can set levels for particular Java classes, so that if a particular class spits out lots of warnings, you can set the log level for that class to ERROR to suppress all the warning messages.

[Read more...](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-log4j-and-how-do-i-use-it.html)

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of log4j is in its architecture of appenders and layouts. As mentioned by previous poster, you change the aspect of logging of your application without much hassle, most of the time it's just a matter of simple configuration. One of the usages I would add on my part is centralized logging which can be added to your application without touching its code base. For example - look at [this](http://www.moonlit-software.com).