# can you help what log4j is and what is good for?

Tags: log4j

guys. I understand my questions can sound a little stupid, but I will ask them nevetheless.

What is log4j ? I understand that it is some kind of sruff that let me gathering some information about my system during the execution.

But, I think this is a little fuzzy. Please, anyone can you explain what is log4j ? 
Where I can use it? What is it good for ? Maybe any benefits.

Thank you a lot, for any information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the use of Log4j API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492309/what-is-the-use-of-log4j-api)

Comment: thank you, I have read it already. It's not what I am looking for. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at the [official Apache log4j page](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/).  It contains a pretty nice overview of what log4j is, what it's for, and why it's a good tool to use.  Here are a few snippets:

### What is Log4j

Log4j is " ... a logging library for Java."  Clean and simple.

### Where can I use it?

Log4j can be used for java applications.

### What's it good for?

Logging is a great way for debugging your application.  By inserting log statements into your code, you provide a way to track and observe the logic path your code takes.

Issues can be easily focused on when you can narrow down the error to the 10-20 lines of code between log statements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have one more question :)  I am learning android now and I found LogCat and I know that I can display some info for example Log.e("Banana", "Someone eat banana").  Is this the same idea behind LogCat and log4J ?